# Open windows calendar from within app in narrow view

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

so all I want to do is to open the calendar app from within my application and the calendar should open in narrow view. The AppointmentManager doesn't seem to give me that possibility so I tried differently. I had success with navigating to the uri "wlcalendar:" like:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("wlcalendar:"), new LauncherOptions(){ DesiredRemainingView = ViewSicePreference.UseMore });
```

But this only works with a debuger attached. If I just run the app, it opens the calendar as desired and crashes. With debugger attached it'll just work, but wrapping the line with a trycatch the error will say Access Denied.

Any suggestion is welcome =)